# Automatically add image to PDF links within WooCommerce product tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Within each product page we have a bunch of tabs and some of them contain links to other websites and some contain PDF links.

What I'd like to do is somehow find the PDF links within each tab and add the following class to them:  pdf-icon.  This class would have the following CSS:

```
.pdf-icon::before {
  content: url(image.png) " ";
}
```

Is there a way to do this with PHP or Javascript?

BTW, the site I'm talking about is http://www.ibisci.com and an example product is http://www.ibisci.com/product/ib56000b-hr-2025-high-resolution-electrophoresis-dna-start-up-kit.  Scroll down to see the product tabs and click on "Operation Manual".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggest adding jQuery tag to this question since it's used on the page for tabs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update:**

OP's page uses jQuery for the tabs.  However, the links within the tab content are regular links. So the method below will work, but a jQuery solution might be a better option.

**original:**

There are many solutions to this problem. The method below is very basic to illustrate one method. It assumes href is a url and cycles through links on the page looking for the .pdf extension.  These have a class applied to make them red.

**Run the code snippet to test**

```html
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .myclass { color: red; }
</style>   

<h2>Find PDF Links</h2>    
<ol>    
    <li><a href="page1.pdf">example1.pdf</a>   
    <li><a href="page1.pdf">example2.pdf</a>    
    <li><a href="page1.html">example3.html</a> 
    <li><a href="page1.pdf">example4.pdf</a> 
</ol>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    
   var i, links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    
    for(i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].href.match(/.pdf/ig)) links[i].className = 'myclass';
    }
    
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```